# Django migration would delete important table

Tags: django-migrations

**SHORT VERSION:**  Django's migration subsystem seems to want to drop and re-create my table, rather than just adding a column.  How can I fix that?

**LONG VERSION:**

I'd like to add a field to one of my Django 3.0 models.  No biggie, right?

1. add field to the class definition
2. `manage.py makemigrations`
3. `manage.py migrate`

So there's a strange issue....when I run `makemigrations`, I see this in the output:

```
Migrations for 'api':
  api/migrations/0006_auto_20200814_0953.py
    - Delete model APISearch
[snip]
    - Create model APISearch
[snip]
```

And sure enough, there are instructions in the resulting migrations to delete and then create an `APISearch` model.

That would be very bad...APISearch is a real table in my database, containing important data.

I think the issue has to do with the fact that a long time ago, `APISearch` was a proxy class (it has long since been changed to a concrete class).  I can't figure out how Django is determining proxy-ness, so that I can correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.

1. Edit the migration that originally created the class:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='APISearch',
            fields=[
            ],
            options={
                'proxy': True,    # explicitly set this to False
                'indexes': [],
            },
            bases=('foo.search',),
        ),
    ]
```

2. Create an empty migration, and use the `AddField` method to do what I want

```
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='apisearch',
            name='my_new_field',
            field=models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True),
        ),
    ]
```